# Clickhouse maximum amount of materialized views per base table

Tags: statistics, aggregation, clickhouse, materialized-views

Is there any limits or recommendation for maximum amount of materialized views per base table?

I aim to generate several statistics reports from a table containing raw data (which contains up to 1B records). Instead of generating a single materialized view for all kinds of reports, I want to create smaller MVs (eg hourly statistics, daily statistics, statistics broken down by location/device/demographic/etc). Right now it seems to be around 12 MVs, but it will grow in future, while adding new reports.

Will CH handle this? Or should I look for different approach to achieve my goal? Unfortunately I couldn’t find anything answering this questions in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No any rules. Every system is uniq.

I would say that 10 MV is over too many.

But MV slow down inserts. If your ingestion is OK then 12 is OK for you.

> hourly statistics, daily statistics, statistics broken down by location/device/demographic/etc)

From my experience I would create 2 MV:

- hourly statistics with dimensions: location, device, demographic
- weekly statistics with dimensions: location, device, demographic

Also check projections https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJ5VuLr2k5k

Maybe you can create projections against your main table. OR maybe it has sense to create projections against MV.

Comment: Great video, I'll look deeper into projections, thanks!
Just one more question if you don't mind. If using a single MV for hourly statistics with n dimensions (let's say 10), I'll need to create a MV as `SELECT GROUP BY (user, hour, dimension_1, ..., dimension_n).`. Which means there won't be that much of unique rows, because of dozens of possible combinations with dimensions. So, my MV will look almost like the base table, collapsing each 1k records into ~100 records per hour. It looks odd. Like I could just use native queries on the base table instead. I feel like I'm missing something here

Comment: You're right. MVs work if they have 100 times / 1000 times fewer rows than the source table. It's up to you. I suggest to not include high cardinality dimensions like user. Up to you if narrow MV works for then use it. You just need to find some balance because if you create 40 MV, then you will do 41 inserts, each MV is a table and CH creates part for them too.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can not drop users from aggregation because all our statistics is user based. And even more: I need a possibility to filter data based on some  dimensions, but this is what I may achieve with projections. I’ll be experimenting with different combinations of mvs and projections on live data then. Thanks again, all your answers are extremely helpful!

Comment: For those who are interested: I ended up with having just one hourly MV which lovers my 300M rows table to just 9M. So that this hourly MV stores pre-aggregated date, and then I just finalize data with simple SQL queries with GROUP clause. And it still works ridiculously fast. Thanks again!